# Android OpenCV to transmit image via socket

Tags: android, sockets, opencv, mat

I am using OpenCV for Android to write a socket that transmits an image to a server written in Python.

This applications is based on Tutorial 3 given by OpenCV for Android v2.4.8. It works as follows: when the user touches the screen, an image is captured and stored in the internal storage of the phone. That image is then transmitted via socket.

The problem is that the socket connection is never established after the image is captured and I cannot figure out why. This is a code snippet of `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                               "/sample_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
        mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
        Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        StartSocket();

        return false;
    }
```

And here is the code for `StartSocket()`. Note that I have tried this code in another Android application to send a text file through socket and it was successful.

```
private void StartSocket() {

        Log.d("SEND","about to imread the img");
        img = Highgui.imread(fileName);
        Log.d("SEND","just finished with imread");

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {   
                    Socket s = new Socket("192.168.19.128", 6000);

                    //--- SEND IMAGE TO SERVER ---//

                    byte[] data = new byte[(int) (img.total()*img.channels())];
                    img.get(0,0,data);

                    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    dout.write(data);
                    dout.flush();


                    //--- RECEIVE TEXT FROM SERVER ---//
                    int charsRead = 0;
                    char[] buffer = new char[1024];

                        Log.d("RECEIVE","about to receive");

                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                        while ((charsRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            serverMsg += new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead);
                            Log.d("Received char",serverMsg);
                        }
                        Log.d("Received msg",serverMsg); */

                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                msgReceived = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgReceived);
                                msgReceived.setText(serverMsg);
                            }
                        });

                        dout.close();
                        s.close(); //close socket

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            t.start();
    }
```

Can anyone guide me for what could be the reason that the socket connection is not established? Please note that all necessary permissions are added to the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the problem was with the network. I am running the server on a Linux-based virtual machine, which was not bridged with the LAN.
So discarding other issues with my code (like receiving a corrupted image on the server's side), the socket connection is established successfully.